# Reactjs onMouseLeave Doesn't work until i move cursor outside of whole page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using MUi and React, onMouseEnter works actually fine, but onMouseLeave doesn't work until i put cursor out of page.

What's the solution really? is there any lack of codes? Thanks.

I wrote everything that is needed to write here but i needed more typing so stackoverflow let me ask my question.

[image]

[image]

```
export default function Home() {
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);
  const open = Boolean(anchorEl);

  const handleClick = (event) => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };
  const handleClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
  };

  return (
    <Box p={20}>
      <Grid container spacing={5}>
        <Grid Item>
          <Button
            variant="contained"
            id="fade-button"
            aria-controls={open ? "fade-menu" : undefined}
            aria-haspopup="true"
            aria-expanded={open ? "true" : undefined}
            onMouseEnter={handleClick}
          >
            Hover Menu
          </Button>
          <Menu
            id="fade-menu"
            MenuListProps={{
              "aria-labelledby": "fade-button",
            }}
            anchorEl={anchorEl}
            open={open}
            onMouseLeave={handleClose}
            TransitionComponent={Fade}
          >
            <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Profile</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>My account</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Logout</MenuItem>
          </Menu>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Comment: call `onMouseLeave={handleClose}` on button element.

Comment: I suppose Menu uses portal and takes full screen to let you close it when clicking outside, so like mentioned above - move your `onMouseLeave` to Button element. But it may make it closing when you leave the Button to click something in the menu

Comment: @AnkitTiwari Thanks, Did that just right now and thing happened is menu is broke, it closes as soon as it opens!

Comment: Because it creates an element that takes full screen and is over all other elements

Comment: @kerelape Thanks, well maybe i have a solution for that but as i said in previous comment it doesn't open anymore although i removed onMouseLeave on menu to make sure and put it just in Button!

Comment: Try putting `onMouseLeave` into `MenuListProps`

Comment: @kerelape Thanks alot, You were absoloutely right! there is a tag with presentation role after menu opens, here is the picture "i.imgur.com/xkpGnjE.png" and the problem is how to deal with that? Actually MenuListProps doesn't work either, you were right earlier it's about the element

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-water-yp4c82?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @kerelape Really appreciate your help, but i want do something like this "https://i.imgur.com/GuBjvpc.png" as you can see in google could platform, is this a right way to do it with menu?

Comment: Not with the Menu component, try using MenuList and positioning it on your own